# List of variables by different functions in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, global, local, visual-studio-extensions

Is there anyway in Visual Studio to display a list of variables created and the different sub procedures or functions that use them? I am trying to change some global variables into local variables that I wrote thinking they were going to be used by many functions and sub procedures instead of just one. I am happy with an add-in solution or extension as well as function inside Visual Studio itself.

Comment: Did you try right-clicking the variable and then "Find all references"?

Comment: @kamikaze yes, but then I have to go through the code and record what sub procedures and functions they are used in myself. I'd want a tool that can do this for me. I guess I'll just have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool for this. Install ReSharper, right-click on any variable (public or private), click on `Inspect it...` and then on `Value Tracking`.

It will give you a list of Class.Method.Line where the variable is used. You can then export the result in a .txt / .xml or .html file.

Note that you can download a 30-days trial for free. Give it a try. Cheers.